# How to work with columns aggregation in DataFrame in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I think that pivot table could be OK but I am not sure...

I have DataFrame like below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : [1, 2, 2, 1, 3],
                   "status" : ["B2", "B2", "B2", "C1", "C1"],
                   "amount" : [100, 200, 410, 500, 300]})

  ID status  amount
0   1     B2     100
1   2     B2     200
2   2     B2     410
3   1     C1     500
4   3     C1     300
```

Needed:

Group by `ID`, `status`(B2, C1) to compute every group's `amount` sum, and the group `size`. then transform the result output.

the output has 5 columns.

```
0. ID        -> `ID`
1. B2-count  -> <`ID`, `status`-B2> Numbers
2. B2-amount -> <`ID`, `status`-B2> amount sums
3. C1-count  -> <`ID`, `status`-C1> Numbers
4. C1-amount -> <`ID`, `status`-C1> amount sums
```

Results:

```
   ID  B2-count  B2-amount  C1-count  C1-amount
0   1       1.0      100.0       1.0      500.0
1   2       2.0      610.0       NaN        NaN
2   3       NaN        NaN       1.0      300.0
```

Comment: What code have you run so far.  show what you have tried.

Comment: This is same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65491135/aggregation-of-sum-and-status-in-dataframe-in-python-pandas

Comment: Yes but there is no answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregate DataFrame base on list values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62835143/aggregate-dataframe-base-on-list-values)

Answer (score 0):

Try `groupby` with `unstack` and `sort_index`

```
df1 = (
    df.set_index(["ID", "status"])
    .groupby(level=[0, 1])
    .agg(["count", "sum"])
    .unstack(1)
    .sort_index(axis=1, level=2)
)
print(df1)

      amount                    
        count    sum count    sum
status     B2     B2    C1     C1
ID                               
1         1.0  100.0   1.0  500.0
2         2.0  610.0   NaN    NaN
3         NaN    NaN   1.0  300.0
```

---

If you need to flatten the columns from the multi index, just re-assign them

```
df1.columns = [f'{z}-{y.replace("sum","amount")}' for x,y,z in df1.columns]

    B2-count  B2-amount  C1-count  C1-amount
ID                                          
1        1.0      100.0       1.0      500.0
2        2.0      610.0       NaN        NaN
3        NaN        NaN       1.0      300.0
```